# In Powershell, how to use the scpclient download method from the rencissh dll?

Tags: .net, powershell, ssh, powershell-2.0, scp

i'm trying to use the "download" method from the Renci SSHNet Library (https://sshnet.codeplex.com/), in Powershell.

Here is a part of my script:

```
$scp = New-Object Renci.SShNet.ScpClient($ssh.ConnectionInfo)

$scp.Download("/path/to/file",(Get-Item '.\clef.gpg'))

$scp.Disconnect()
```

When im executing my script, i get the following error (sry, my Posh is in french):

```
 Exception lors de l'appel de « Download » avec « 2 » argument(s) : « La référence     d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet. »
Au niveau de C:\Users\olivier\Downloads\4_scripts\powershell\project1\Renci\test.ps1 : 62 Caractère : 18
+     $scp.Download <<<< ("/path/to/file",(Get-Item '.\clef.gpg') )
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

In fact, i don't know what is the 2nd parameter of the **ScpClient.Download** method. In the documentation, i see that:

```
public void Download(
    string filename,
    FileInfo fileInfo
)
```

And "fileInfo" is described as:

> fileInfo
>   Type: System.IO.FileInfo
>   Local file information.

I know that the `Get-Item` command returns a [System.IO.FileInfo] object so this is why i tried that in my code, but it doesn't work :(

Anyone knows how to use this method correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a call to the `ScpClient.Connect` method - `$scp.Connect()`.

Other than that, what you are doing should be fine, and should work.

Comment: Oooh... i didnt saw! In other part of my script, i have plenty of `ssh.Connect()` but for scp i was obsessed by this download method... Thanks!